# How to get a variable from $.ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to get a var declared in success function. but I get "undefined".

```
$("#frm-registro").submit(function() {
    x=existeCedula();
    /*Here i get "undefined"*/
    alert(x);
});

function existeCedula(){
    var serializedForm = $("#frm-registro").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>site/find_ced_ins",
        async: true,
        data: serializedForm,       
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you don't return the variable in ajax, you put the processing callback *inside* the success `function(data) {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls occur asynchronously, so your method is returning before the call finishes.  You need to do something like this:

```
$("#frm-registro").submit(function() {
    x=existeCedula();
});

function existeCedula(){
    var serializedForm = $("#frm-registro").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>site/find_ced_ins",
        async: true,
        data: serializedForm,       
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //Resume your logic here
        }
    });
}
```

You can also do something like this, where callback is a function:

```
function existeCedula(callback){
    var serializedForm = $("#frm-registro").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>site/find_ced_ins",
        async: true,
        data: serializedForm,       
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still won't work.  As the example I put shows, you can't return from a success function.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't understand very well

Comment: You have a return in the success function, but those calls are asynchronous.  Look at my code and compare it to yours.  Look at where my alert is.  Your alert runs before the web call returns.

Comment: Please give me an example with a return. I need to get a value in the other function. Thanks

Comment: I really don't want to show an alert. I want to get a value in other function

Comment: I'm not really sure how else to explain it, the only way to get a return is to disable async which is deprecated.  You *cannot* return from an ajax call.  You will need to pass the rest of your logic as a function.  The alert is just an example, you can pass any function call you want in, but you can't return from in that success loop.